# IAM Permision Denied - Dialog flow Gcloud Twilio Integration

Tags: dialogflow-es

Currently i am trying integrate twilio with dialog flow by running in GCloud.
I am facing below error.

```
2021-02-01 12:12:58.223 HKT(node:14) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: IAM permission 'dialogflow.sessions.detectIntent' on 'projects/sample1-ecji/agent' denied.
```

Already added `Dialogflow Client API` & `Dialogflow Client Admin`

Please advise

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49673575/google-dialogflow-permission-denied-exception    This seems like it might answer you question

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. I didn't use the correct service account .
Now it is working after using the correct service account.